# Find a power series for $f(z)=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{1-wz}dw$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find a power series for $$f(z)=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{1-wz}dw$$
What I did:

For $|wz|<1$, i.e. $|z|<\frac{1}{|w|}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{1-wz}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(wz)^k$$
So
$$f(z)=\int^1_0 \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(wz)^k dw=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\int^1_0(wz)^kdw=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}z^k\frac{1}{k+1}w^{k+1}|^1_0=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{z^k}{k+1}$$
Could anyone check my solutions? Since we need $|z|<\frac{1}{|w|}$ here, would there be a problem by using $w$ here?

Comment: I think $w \in [0,1]$, so $\frac{1}{|w|} \in [1,\infty)$, so $|z| < 1$.

Comment: That's good and nice to get the power series expansion about $0$. The integral defines $f$ as a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : t\geqslant 1\}$. If you want a power series expansion with a different centre, it's probably easiest to first identify what $f$ is.

Comment: @DanielFischer can you expand on what you mean here?

Comment: @qbert I mean that what the OP did is a good way to obtain the Maclaurin series of $f$. And that if one wants to get a power series expansion about a different point, say $27 + 5i$, it's probably easier to identify $f$ and then work with $-\frac{\log (1-z)}{z}$ than to fiddle around with the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dw}{1-wz}$ to obtain that expansion.

Comment: @DanielFischer may you please help here? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2860170/140308